# Will delayed job run based on server time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job in my rails application. i want to run a delayed_job based on a table column which is saved in UTC. My server setting is in EST. Delayed job will take UTC or EST?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `active_record_delayed_job` then your application time zone as set in `application.rb` will be used.

Following is taken from delayed_job source (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/blob/master/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb#L97)

```
    # Get the current time (GMT or local depending on DB)
    # Note: This does not ping the DB to get the time, so all your clients
    # must have syncronized clocks.
    def self.db_time_now
      if Time.zone
        Time.zone.now
      elsif ::ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone == :utc
        Time.now.utc
      else
        Time.now
      end
    end
```

and this is used in `reserve_with_scope` which queries the DB for available jobs (starting in line 56)

If you are not sure which timezone is set in your application, you can use the following from the rails console

```
2.1.4 :005 > Rails.application.config.time_zone
 => "Helsinki"
```

or

```
2.1.4 :007 > Time.zone.name
 => "Helsinki"
```